# Extent Report version 5.0.9 get Pass and Fail totals in Selenium JUnit Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I recently upgraded my Extent Report in my pom file

```
     <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
     <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.6</version>
     Changed to <version>5.0.9</version>
```

In version 4.1.6 I was able to obtain pass and fail counts from my report with the following line. I know the totals are displayed in the report, but need to have these totals displayed on the console.

Assume my ExtentReports report;

```
    report.getStats().getEventsCountPass() // this give pass total

    report.getStats().getEventsCountFail() // this give fail total
```

I can't figure out the equivalent in version 5.0.9. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have looked at the version 5.0.9 extentreports docs and didn't see the method equivalent.